# Powershell: Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding always returns error 183 - netsh http add sslcert works

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a small Powershell script which extracts the Thumbprint from a given SSL certificate and uses this to bind the certificate to a given port.

PSVersion is 5.1.19041.1682

I'm using this command to bind the certificate to the port:

```
$ip = "0.0.0.0"
$Port = 8085
Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding -IpPort ${ip}:$Port -CertificateHash $certHash -CertificateStoreName $certStore -ApplicationId $appId -NullEncryption $false
```

This fails with the following error message:

> Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding : Eine Datei kann nicht erstellt werden, wenn sie bereits vorhanden ist.
> ...
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 183,Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding

(I don't know the exact translation, but it should be something like "Cannot create a file when that file already exists.")

I am very sure that there are no bindings to the given port, because

```
netsh http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8085
```

returns an empty list (which is correct).

If I use `netsh http add sslcert` in my Powershell script instead of Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding like this

```
$params_add = "netsh http add sslcert ipport=${ip}:$Port certhash=$certHash appid={$appId}"
cmd.exe /c $params_add
```

it works fine and the binding is also correctly displayed by `netsh http show ...`

**Is there anything wrong with how I use the Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding command?
Or are there any known bugs?**

The only thing I found out by googling is that I'm probably not the only one having problems with this command ....

Is there a powershell-version of `netsh http show sslcert`, something like `Get-NetIPHttpsCertBinding`? I could not find anything like that.